# Как разделить без остатка на C#?

Tags: c#, операторы

Как разделить без остатка (не округлить а просто "отрезать" остаток после запятой) на C#?

UPD

Я пытаюсь простой таймер написать для Unity :)

- Пользователь вводит часы, минуты и секунды, (для каждого своя
  переменная int).
- Затем все это преобразуется в общее кол-во секунд и присваивается переменной float.
- Каждкю секунду отнимается единица с помощью    Time.deltaTime (последнее выдает float, поэтому и нужно было хранить секунды во float).
- После чего секунды снова пересчитываются в часы,минуты и секунды и присваиваются соответствующим переменным.

  Вот тут и появляется проблема: Нужно либо конвертировать секунды из float в int, либо изначально все переменные сделать float но "отрезать" знаки после запятой.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66631/discussion-on-question-by-rumata------c).

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/DTGGxw

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    double x = 1e11;
    Console.WriteLine((long)x / 60);
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(x / 60));
  }
}
```

И вообще, нет никакого смысла использовать дробные числа для времени. Используй целые секунды или миллисекунды, как везде.

Comment: Извините, для меня здесь пока слишком много магии) вы не могли бы пояснить?

1e11 это 1 * 10^11 (один умножить на 10 в степени 11)?
(long) - Это некий "целочисленный тип данных" (зачем он здесь)? Math.Floor - округление? Судя по ссылке насколько я понимаю в обоих случаях  вывод в консоль = 1666666666 - что это дает? И как задавать время для таймера в этом варианте?

Comment: 1. Да. 2. Да, 64 битный. У double только 53 значащих бита, т. е. только целые числа до 5^53 представляются точно. У long получается 63, т. е. ни переполнения, ни потери точности не будет (при условии, что число не превосходило 2^53). 3. Это два условно эквивалентных способа. Точнее, они эквивалентны при x in 0 to 2^53. При других гарантировать не могу. А результат деления имеет 6 в периоде и обычное округление дало бы последнюю цифру 7, а не 6.

Comment: почему `floor` то, а не `truncate`?, для `-7.1` получите `-8`, что явно не "отрезание" дробной части. По условию, конечно, у автора вряд ли будут отрицательные значения, но все же, имхо метод не тот.

Comment: @teran, не знаю. Просто обычно его использую. И, вроде, в вопросе про отрицательные числа нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy традиционно `ceil` округляет в сторону +бесконечности (вверх), `floor` в сторону минус бесконечности (вниз), `round` делает обычное, или банковское округление, а `truncate` просто отсекает дробную часть (т.е округляет в сторону нуля всегда)

Comment: @teran, ну ok. Можешь написать об этом в своём ответе. А так-то ясно - не просто так же они полом и потолком называются :)